# How to Search for a total Range in another Range in Excel

Tags: excel, range, lookup, sumifs

In Excel I need to Sum Values, but only if ANY of a full column of text values appears in a specific column. In other words: "Sum the Values [Column X] where Country=Y, but only where ID= [anything from A2:A2000, formatted as text]. If the ID isn't one of those values in the range, I don't want the Row value for Country=Y to be Summed.

I can't do this line-by-line, so I'm looking for the syntax of a range vs. another range., since the ID "keys" are in a separate column than the countries to be Summed by.

Column A = individual Countries, in a separate table we have a very long list of "valid" IDs. From the main data table, I want to Sumif Widgets column by Country, but only where ID = one of the IDs in the "valid' ID table.

Comment: This is a good example of what databases are good for.  If you're not constrained to Excel, you should give serious thought to doing this in a database.  MS Access is a good entry-level one that will help you write queries to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT`.

Let's say Sheet1 column A has the countries, Sheet1 column B has the IDs, Sheet1 column C has the values, Sheet2 column A has the IDs to match and all tables have headers in row 1. This formula is being put on Sheet1.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$100,$A$2:$A$100,"CountryName",$B$2:$B$100,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100))`

`SUMIFS` gives the sum of range C2:C100, for which the range A2:A100 corresponds to the text "Countryname", and for which the IDs in range B2:B100 correspond to the IDs on the other sheets. The values returned are in an array, and as such, you uses `SUMPRODUCT` to sum them up.

Change the range references accordingly.